# NHibernate Bringing old data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I'm working with c# and nhibernate to access the database.
I have two or three terminals who can realize same actions, like edit, or remove entities from the same DB.
My problem is that my terminal does not realize if another terminal made any change on the database, although i refresh the data executing the queries again.
I think it's due to the cache.
I've tryed Flush() and Evict() commands with no results.
I wish somebody could help me, sorry for my terrible english

-----Info Added -------

It's a c# desktop application.
I don't see any errors, the problem is that when i edit or delete i need to know if the entity was modified from another terminal. and when i bring the entity from database, i'm not seeig the changes mades from another terminal until y restart the application.

The session is created by the next code :

```
[PossibleLongOperation]
        private void DoConnectionWork(string nhibernateConfigPath)
        {
            String appPath = Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()).Location).FullName;
            String serializablefilePath = Path.Combine(appPath, "configuration.serialized");
            try
            {
                if (IsConfigurationFileValid(serializablefilePath))
                {
                    Configuration = LoadConfigurationFromFile(serializablefilePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    // configuration is immutable, store last returned value
                    Configuration = new Configuration();
                    Configuration.Configure(nhibernateConfigPath);
                    Configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(ObjectEntity).Assembly);
                    SaveConfigurationToFile(serializablefilePath, Configuration);
                    new SchemaUpdate(Configuration).Execute(true, true);
                    Console.WriteLine(@"Se solicitó la actualización de datos");
                }
                //NHibernateSchemaExport();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //if(File.Exists(serializablefilePath))
                //    File.Delete(serializablefilePath);
                throw new GenericRepositoryException(string.Format("Error while configuring NHibernate: {0}.", ex.Message), ex);
            }

            try
            {
                SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //if (File.Exists(serializablefilePath))
                //    File.Delete(serializablefilePath);
                throw new GenericRepositoryException(string.Format("Error while building NH session factory: {0}.", ex.Message), ex);
            }
        }
```

----------Added-------------

this is the exception i get after Clear() the session

```
09-02-2012 13:22:54|Error|Error:  
NHibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 394, of entity: Model.Pedido
   en NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.CheckUniqueness(EntityKey key, Object obj) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\StatefulPersistenceContext.cs:línea 688
   en NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event, Object entity, IEntityPersister persister) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cs:línea 227
   en NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsDetached(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cs:línea 186
   en NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultUpdateEventListener.cs:línea 29
   en NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cs:línea 53
   en NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:línea 2666
   en NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Update(Object obj) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:línea 524
   en Besnik.GenericRepository.NHibernate.NHibernateUnitOfWork.Update[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   en Besnik.GenericRepository.GenericRepository`2.Update(TEntity entity)
   en Services.Services.Implementation.PedidoServiceImpl.<>c__DisplayClass8.<Anular>b__7() en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\Services\Services\Implementation\PedidoServiceImpl.cs:línea 72
   en Services.Transaction.Transaction.Execute(Action transactionalAction, Action`1 onException) en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\Services\Transaction\Transaction.cs:línea 32
```

Comment: Is this a web application, desktop application? How is the session context being created? Are you using NHibernate versioning? What errors, if any, are you seeing e.g. `StaleStateException` ? We're going to need more information from you to be able to give some clear answers to this one, I think.

Comment: i added the information you need. thanks

Comment: that's how your session factory is being built from configuration, but how about your sessions - are you using Session per form, Session per thread, etc?

Comment: i have one session for all application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try clearing the L1 session cache, by session.Clear() ?

Comment: Yes, i tried that, and that worked for update the data, but then the session crashed and started to give errors in other operations

Comment: Your session shouldn't be that long running anyway, event if you are doing session per presenter / form or something. What errors does the session give ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using session per application, that is a very bad practice.

Comment: You can check on the internet some info about "lifespan of NHibernate session" or something.

What I would suggest you is to open close session for each request, the simplest way possible, the shortest lifespan of a session. When this starts to create problems for you, try to explore how to use session per form or something, utilizating lazy loads, L1 cache etc...

Anyway, session per application is wrong.